# submitting a form on checkbox click in JSP

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a HTML form in JSP page. It has one text field, checkbox, submit and back buttons.

```
<form name="inForm" method="post" action="" onSubmit="return formSubmitted();">
     <table border="0">
       <tr>
         <td valign="middle">Serial Number:</td>
           <td valign="middle">
              <input type="text" name="serialNumber" size="30" maxlength="50" value="<%= serialNumber %>"/>
           </td>
           <td valign="middle">                    
              <input type="checkbox" name="userSelection" value="YES" <%=dispOrderChecked%> **onChange="this.form.submit()**"> Display  Data in sorting order
           </td> 
        </tr>

        <tr>
           <td>
              <table border="0" width="100%">
                 <tr align="center">
                     <td align="center">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" onClick="document.pressed=this.value"/>
                    <%
                     if (SerialNumber != null)
                     {
                    %>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Back" onClick="document.pressed=this.value"/>
                   <%
                     }
                    %>
                </td>
             </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
```

When I click on submit button the form is submitting and working as expected. I also want to submit the form when user clicks on the checkbox. I have tried `onChange="this.form.submit()"` and the form is not submitted.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function formSubmitted()
{
    if (document.pressed == 'Search' || document.inForm.userSelection.checked)    
    {       
        return validateSubmittedForm();
    }
    else
    {
        if (document.pressed == 'Back')
        {            
            window.history.back();
        }
    }    
    return false;
}

function validateSubmittedForm()
{
    var serNum = document.inForm.serialNumber.value;
    if (serNum != "" && serNum.length > 3)
    {
        document.inForm.action = "studentFound.jsp";
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
      if(serNum.length < 3)
      {           
        alert("Please enter at least 3 characters of the serial number");
        document.inForm.serialNumber.focus()
        return false;
      }          
    }
}
```

Help me in fixing this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi, its working fine just change name of submit button to something else because its conflicting form submit i.e : `name="submit"` to `name="searchs"` and try again .For reason check [this](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) link inside that `Additional Notes` sections .

Comment: Hi Swati, I changed the button name to btnSubmit and also kept the alert statement in formSubmitted() method and alert is not showing when I checked the check box and also not happened anything instead of refreshing the current page.

Comment: I see this is because only submit button can trigger onsubmit event . Here you go [alternate solution](https://jsfiddle.net/5m4cv7tn/)

Comment: Hi Swati, yes I'm able to submit the form now. But I want to send/pass the 'Search' value to the formSubmitted() method on checkbox click. Please let me know how can I pass the 'Search' value.

Comment: It is passing that value do `console.log(document.pressed)` you will see its value . i.e : `Search`

Comment: Hi Swati, I have checked and getting the 'Search'. Whatever the form I'm using to search the same form is displaying in the header in results.jsp page . Now in the results page when I unchecked the check box,then I'm getting the error saying **document.inForm.submit.click is not a function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230228/discussion-between-swati-and-user2636874).